# htaccess redirect depending on text after /

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a .htaccess related question that I need help redirecting.

I have a directory in which I keep multiple other directories, one of which is my websites directory.

I have my .htaccess file already setup to default into the sub directory in which my website is held and display the url as though it isn't located in a subdirectory, i.e. "reinhards.co/", instead of "reinhards.co/reinhards.co"

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# In Root directory
# WPhtC: Disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?reinhards.co$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/reinhards.co/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /reinhards.co/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?reinhards.co$
RewriteRule ^(/)$ reinhards.co/index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

However, I need the following to happen, when someone types in:

reinhards.co/xxxx

to redirect to reinhards.co/reinhards.co/xxxx , but still display the url as reinhards.co/xxxx

I would also love the functionality to say, if someone typed in

reinhards.co/yyyy to just redirect to
reinhards.co/reinhards.co/yyyy as that is a valid webpage, but still display the url as reinhards.co/yyyy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /test/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=229
RewriteRule ^.*$ /supermodel/? [R=301,L]
```

something like this.

Comment: Thank you, would you mind breaking it down so I can understand what is being done here? I'm still learning htaccess characters and syntax

Comment: 1 line say if user go to http://site.blah and path is /test/
2 line say if GET param is id=229
3 line say generate url http://site.blah/supermodel/?id=229 and redirect user to it.

Comment: Could I also say RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/test/ RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=229 with the same rule and it would redirect every time the request wasn't test?

Comment: Or am I misunderstanding and that query searches for the I'd and only redirects if the request uri is equal to 229?

Comment: yes, you just can remove second line to redirect all who came to /test/ path

Comment: Last couple questions, are the rewrite rules and conditions read from top to bottom unless they hit a [L] then quit, and should this htaccess file be both in the root folder and the sub folder ?

Comment: Yes and second is I think the rules is recursive to subfolders.

Comment: Much appreciated Eugene thank you for the explanations I think I can now form the htaccess file to how I see fit. I'm sure I'll come to another road block but as far as this question is concerned I feel it was answered adequately